# Need clarification with XML files in Android and app architecture

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm writing an Android app that is a multiple choice question test on 4 subjects (Geography, Biology, Philosophy, Economics). Each subject has 10 questions. Each question has 4 optional answers, 1 of them is correct.

So these are my questions:

1. Is it better to store Q&As in separate XML files for each subject or have 1 XML with 40 questions for all subjects?
2. Where do I store that XML file(s)? Some tutorials suggest to create and store in ***res/raw*** directory whilst other suggest ***assets*** directory?
3. Anyone have a good example of **XMLPullParser** or other XML Parsers to actually read the XML and get the values from it? As far as I've understood the parser reads from the start to end of the specific tag, you then need to initialize the values to a string and then show in the widget, is it right? How do I get the right answers, do I need to create a separate list or array with answers to check if user's input is the same as in that array?
4. How do I identify the right answers within XML to check in Java afterwards? I haven't worked with XML before, don't quiet understand it. Read the tutorials but don't seem to get it right. Would it be something like this?

   ```
   <mcq>
   <questions>
       <question>What is the capital of Belarus?</question>
       <id>1</id>
       <answer1>Kiev</answer1>
       <answer2>Bobruisk</answer2>
       <answer3 valid="true">Minsk</answer3>
      <answer4>Kharkov</answer4>
   </questions>
   </mcq>
   ```

   Sorry for lots of silly questions and thanks in advance

Comment: why are you using xml only for this?

Comment: @SuhailMehta, well that's a trial, I will need to extend it after that anyway. I'm using XML as it is the requirement. After I manage this, I can implement more questions and probably use DB to access XML.

Answer (score 1):

First two questions pretty much boil down to a matter of choice, do whatever you deem more convenient.

Third and fourth, if you are not familiar with XML and its parsing, I'd suggest (if you don't have a specific requirement to use XML) to go for JSON format instead.

In my opinion (and that is just an opinion), it doesn't get much easier to extract data for such a task as the one you describe than using the org.json package.

Possible structure for a single subject:

```
[
    { "id": 1,
        "question": "What is your favourite colour?",
        "answers": [ "red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "blue" ],
        "correct": 2
    },
    { "id": 2,
        ...
    }
]
```

You'd have your answers as an array of strings in there, and "correct" as the index of an array position.

You could parse this (structure in a string called inputString) using org.json like this (pseudocode):

```
JSONArray myTopic = new JSONArray(inputString);
JSONObject[] myQuestions = new JSONObject[myTopic.length];
for(int i=0; i< myQuestions.length; i++) {
    myQuestions[i] = myTopic.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Then iterate through myQuestions to extract the data per question, you should be able to work that out from here. For example, getting the answers from myQuestions[0]:

```
JSONArray myAnswers = myQuestions[0].getJSONArray("answers");
```

Comment: I've seen people using it and seems more convenient. Cheers! Will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to go with list in one file for your scenario.

you need to store all the subjects within one file like below.

```
 <subject name="Geography">
    <question text="Question 1">
        <option text="Option A">
        <option text="Option B">
        <option text="Option C">
        <option text="Option D">
        <answer text="Option A">
    <question>
 </subject>
 <subject name="Biology">
    <question text="Question 1">
        <option text="Option A">
        <option text="Option B">
        <option text="Option C">
        <option text="Option D">
        <answer text="Option B">
    <question>
    <question text="Question 2">
        <option text="Option A">
        <option text="Option B">
        <option text="Option C">
        <option text="Option D">
        <answer text="Option C">
    <question>
 </subject>
```

and Corresponding Java Classes can be like below.

```
class Test
{
    List<Subject> subjects
}

class Subject
{
    List<Questions> listOfQuestions;
}

class Question
{
    String question;
    List<Option> listOfOptions;
    String answer;
}
```

Here is how you can use DOM Xml parser of java With Xpath ( Parsing code is not for Above XML its just sample how you can parse xml with DOM )

```
File xmlFile = new File("File Name Here");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

String reportContentTagXpath = "//DicomAttribute[@keyword='ContentSequence']";
Node itemNode = getNodeByXPath(document, reportContentTagXpath);

private static Node getNodeByXPath(Object object, String xpath) throws XPathExpressionException
{
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = xpath;
    Node itemNodes = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(object, XPathConstants.NODE);
    return itemNodes;
}
```